# tsconfig not used by typescript-eslint

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

In a new project, I installed `typescript`, `eslint`, `@typescript-eslint/parser`, `@typescipt-eslint/eslint-plugin`. I also added the following `.eslintrc` file:

```
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"]
}
```

and the following `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

The problem is that the option from `tsconfig.json` is not applied when I run the command `eslint`. It works as expected with the command `tsc`, though.

For example, with a file `index.ts` containing:

```
function sum(a, b) {}
```

If I run `npx eslint index.js`, I have no error while if I run `tsc --noEmit`, I have two:

- error TS7006: Parameter 'a' implicitly has an 'any' type.
- error TS7006: Parameter 'b' implicitly has an 'any' type.

I would like the `eslint` command to return the same errors as the `tsc` command.
Any idea?

**Edit** I tried with and without the following in the `.eslintrc`:

```
"parserOptions": {
  "project": "./tsconfig.json"
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

typescript-eslint does not report compiler warnings. It only reports warnings generated by its own validation rules. Also, enabling the `strict` option in TypeScript has no effect on the code analysis performed by typescript-eslint, which does not rely on the project settings.

There have been [some discussions](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/662) about creating a new `@typescript-eslint/no-undef` rule (modeled on ESLint [`no-undef`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef) rule) that would catch at least some of the warnings generated by the tsc compiler with strict type checking on.

The best approach for now is probably integrating the execution of `tsc --noEmit` it the lint process.

Comment: could you provide an example of integrating the execution of tsc --noEmit in the lint process?

Comment: @olefrank I don't have an example that runs the tsc executable at hand, but in one of my projects, I'm using the TypeScript compiler API with a minimal set of [options](https://github.com/fasttime/Polytype/blob/0.4.0/tsconfig.json) (including `noEmit`) to do exactly this kind of linting. The key is the function `createProgram` provided by the typescript module, that throws an error - thus stopping the build - when it cannon compile. The code of interest is [here](https://github.com/fasttime/Polytype/blob/0.4.0/test/spec/ts-defs.spec.js). I'll see if I can come up with a simplified example.

Comment: @GOTO0 any update on that simplified example? Maybe there has been some update on eslint-typescript regarding this?